# Error executing the .exe file of my program

Tags: c++, c

I made a ping-pong ball program in C, using Turbo C++ compiler. But the problem is that after compiling the program, an error occurs while running the exe file like below:

[image: error]

So I figured out that this error is maybe because I am using a 64 bit OS, then I tried running it on a 32 bit OS, and the error was like this:

[image: img]

What can I do so that my program is compatible, and that I can directly run the exe file instead of always executing the program.

Comment: Use a compiler that is not 20+ years old. Or try running your program in dosbox.

Comment: Use Visual Studio if you want to create apps/games for Windows. Learning it from the time when you are writing small programs will be very useful when you are making transition to bigger projects.

Comment: MinGW is a compiler thats available in both 32 and 64 bit versions (I compile 32bit code for use on a 64bit machine, most of the time). You can get it, along with an IDE if you get Code::Blocks (with MinGw). CodeBlocks is multi-platform, and I run it on x64 windows, x64 linux and raspberry pi linux. Same with wxWidgets - I write a gui app on windows then compile and run it (without a single modification) on my raspberry pi. (No sales commision! :p They're all free)

Comment: @VikramSingh - Is is called humour

Comment: @EdHeal -Yeah...cool then :)

Comment: Please include the actual information and not links. Some of us don't like following links, and they go stale over time.

Comment: running the exe file is executing the program, so I don't understand what your last statement means

Comment: Also why are you using WinRAR at all? This does not make any sense to me.

Answer (score 3):

Turbo C is a 16-bit compiler for DOS, and it produces 16-bit executable programs.  64-bit versions of Windows do not support running 16-bit DOS programs, since x64 processors don't support [virtual 8086 mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_8086_mode) when running in [long mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_mode).  To run a DOS program in 64-bit Windows, you'd need to use something like [DOSBox](http://www.dosbox.com/), which emulates a processor so it doesn't need the real processor to support virtual 8086 mode.

32-bit Windows does support running 16-bit DOS programs.  It's unclear why WinRAR was involved in your attempt to run your program on 32-bit Windows.  Try running your program from a command prompt to avoid any shell extensions that may be invoking WinRAR for things that it (wrongly) believes are self-extracting archives.

Your best bet, however, is to use a modern compiler.  Turbo C is basically obsolete, since DOS is basically obsolete.  There are a number of of free C/C++ development tools available for modern 32-bit and 64-bit computers, such as Microsoft's [Visual Studio Express](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx) and [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/).

Comment: Thank you I would try to make this program using Microsoft Visual Studio Express :)

Comment: 64-bit windows doesn't support 16-bit programs because [*handles have 32 significant bits on 64-bit Windows. Therefore, handles cannot be truncated and passed to 16-bit applications without loss of data*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384249.aspx) http://superuser.com/a/380462/241386

Comment: I also recommend QtCreator for a free modern C++ compiler+IDE under windows. And no you do not have to write Qt applications to use QtCreator.